# Mod rewrite user URL

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

I'm lost here. I'm using this script to give users the opportunity to enter their username lijke this:domain/username

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ userpage.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This works fine. However, every user has pages I must link to: Video, Music, Images etc...

So I need something like:

```
domain/username/video
```

In php code it must be something like:

```
user.php?user=test&page=video
```

And one other question: What is the preferable way to link in this situation?

```
userpage.php?user=test&page=video
```

or

```
/test/video
```

And finally: Is it possible to deny the possibility to enter the url: 
`domain/userpage.php?user=test&page=video`? Instead just always show: `domain/test/video`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking? Do you need to change the rewrite rule to match the URL site.com/moonwalker/videos? You could try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(images|videos|music)/?$ userpage.php?user=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

**Update**
Just a quick note on the domain/member/videos URL structure. That could end up causing you problems in the future. For instance what if you decide to have a single page that shows all member videos? You'd probably want to URL to look something like site.com/members/videos. That's a problem, because the rewrite rule will also match that, but "members" isn't a member username.

I would probably structure my member page URLs like site.com/user/moonwalker/videos so it doesn't clash with future rewrite rules. You would change the above rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/(images|videos|music)/?$ userpage.php?user=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Then later on you can add a rewrite rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^members/(images|videos|music)/?$ allusers.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

To show all member videos.

Comment: Hmm...I'm trying to do the following:
domain/moonwalker/video

in the background this script is running:
userpage.php?user=moonwalker&page=images

I tried your script but I get 404 error.

Comment: Does the 404 error show which page is not found? i.e. "404 - userpage.php not found"

Comment: This is the complete error:
The requested URL /moonwalker/video was not found on this server.

Comment: The rewrite rule above uses "videos". Not "video".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible by looking at the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /userpage\.php[?\ ]
RewriteRule ^userpage\.php$ - [F]
```

This is necessary as the URL path could already be rewritten by another rule and thus using just `RewriteRule` would match those already rewritten requests too.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong, because a 404 error keeps showing up. And thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: @moonwalker: Where do you want to use that rule?

Comment: @Gumbo: At this moment I'm trying to get everything to work on my local server. So: http://localhost/

Comment: @moonwalker: Yes, but in what [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context)? Server/virtual host configuration or an .htaccess file?

Comment: Oh sorry. No just an .htaccess file.

Comment: @moonwalker: And you’re sure you’re getting a 404 and not a 403?

Comment: @moonwalker: No, the *F* flag should handle that. Um, did you also use the obligatory `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: This is how the code looks like:
[code]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /userpage\.php[?\ ]
RewriteRule ^userpage\.php$ - [F]
[/code]